# Unable to upcast from CloudBlockBlob to CloudBlob

Tags: azure, f#, azure-storage

I must be missing something obvious here, but I find myself unable to do an upcast which I thought was legal. I am trying to upload data to Blob storage in Azure, and would like to use the method [CloudBlob.UploadText(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772818.aspx). However, when I access my blob, I get a [CloudBlockBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758638.aspx) instance, which as far as I can tell inherits from CloudBlob, and the method UploadText is not accessible, so I tried `let blob = targetBlob :> CloudBlob` - which fails miserably, with the message

```
SmallScript.fsx(28,12): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    CloudBlockBlob    
is not compatible with type
    CloudBlob    
The type 'CloudBlockBlob' is not compatible with the type 'CloudBlob'
```

I can upload data just fine using UploadFromStream, but UploadText would be pretty convenient for my purposes. Can anyone help me see what I am missing?

For the record, in case this helps, here is the code that works:

```
let credentials = StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey)
let storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true)
let client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()

let containerName = "numerics"
let container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName)
container.CreateIfNotExists() |> ignore

let targetBlobName = "MiniSparseMatrix.csv"
let targetBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(targetBlobName)

let fileLocation = @"C:\Users\Mathias\Desktop\TestMatrix.txt"
let stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileLocation)
targetBlob.UploadFromStream(stream)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: Can you check if you're using Storage Client library 1.8 or 2.0? The reason I ask this is because `CreateIfNotExists()` on a blob container is in library 2.0. In 1.8, it is named `CreateIfNotExist()` (missing "s").

Comment: I believe this is the October 2012 release of the Azure SDK, if that answers your question. The syntax doesn't seem to be the issue (the script passes and uploads), it's the upcast between the blob types that fails.

Comment: @GauravMantri actually you might be on something, while the script displayed works, in other places container only recognizes CreateIfNotExist, without the s. I'll dig deeper, your hint could be right, i.e. a conflict between library versions.

Comment: Please check if you're referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient (which is version 1.8) or Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (which is version 2.0) library. Version 2.0 is significantly different than 1.8 and some of the methods including UploadText have been removed from 2.0. I wrote some blog posts comparing these 2 versions which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/tag/storage-client-library/. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly referencing multiple versions of libraries? My guess would be that the `CloudBlockBlob` you're getting is not from the same assembly (version) as the one your code references that has the `CloudBlob` type.

If you can comment out the code that doesn't compile, and attach the debugger, you should be able to confirm this by examining the type in the QuickWatch window and looking at its type (look at `.GetType().Assembly` and compare it to `typeof(CloudBlob).Assembly`).